# Django Rest framework: custom API response

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have `Char` objects with ManyToMany relationships to `Source` objects. Because a Char can appear in many Sources and many Sources can contain multiple Chars. The MtM relationship goes through a `through` table which also contains page number. In my API response, which I built using the Django REST framework I want to avoid resolving the full Source title, author etc. for every Char. Rather, in order to reduce the size of the JSON response, I want to refer it by id and include a `sources` section so the client can look it up.

I.e. a client visiting /api/char/26 should get the following response:

```
"chars": [
    {
        "id": 26,
        "name": "龜",
        "locations": [
            {
                "page": 136,
                "source": 1
            },
            {
                "page": 162,
                "source": 1
            }
        ]
    }
],
"sources": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Bruksanvisning Foamglass",
        "author": "Bluppfisk"
    }
]
```

Here's the API view:

```
class CharAPIView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Char.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CharSerializer
```

and the Serializers:

```
class CharSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    locations = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Char
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'locations',)
        depth = 1

    def get_locations(self, obj):
        qset = CharInSource.objects.filter(char=obj)
        return [CharInSourceSerializer(m).data for m in qset]


class CharInSourceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CharInSource
        fields = ('page', 'source',)
```

The problem is I do not know how to hook into the `generics.RetrieveAPIView` class so it will include a list of relevant sources. I've been digging through the source, but I cannot figure out how to even get the pk value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I ended up solving it as follows, by overwriting the `retrieve` method of my view.

```
class CharAPIView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Char.objects.all()

    def retrieve(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        char = CharSerializer(instance).data
        qset = Source.objects.all()
        sources = [SourceSerializer(m).data for m in [i for i in instance.location.all()]]

        return Response({
            'char': char,
            'sources': sources,
        })
```

Comment: Great you solved it! this is exactly what I had envisioned, I'm sorry I didn't get to writing it for you. Very glad you have it figured.

Answer (score 0):

This could be accomplished with another `SerializerMethodField` on your `CharSerializer` and creating a `SourceSerializer`; no extension of the base methods to `GenericAPIView or RetrieveModelMixin`.

```
def SourceSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
         model = Source
         fields = ('id', 'title', 'author') # assuming author is not also a
                                            #  ForeignKey, otherwise returns an id

def CharSerializer(...):
....
sources = SerializerMethodField()
def get_sources(self, obj):
    return SourceSerializer(
         Source.objects.filter(chars__in=[obj.id]).distinct(), 
             many=True).data
class Meta:
    fields = (...,'sources')
```

Assuming the attribute to the MTM model related_name is `chars` you can use `chars__in` and pass a list of `Char` ids; which in this case is the single char we are referencing. This would however contain the sources within each char object instead of outside as you had indicated by the question. However, I imagine you would want to know which sources have which char, as my solution would provide.

Without seeing the exact structure of your models, I cannot be certain of exactly how you should retrieve the Source objects. I feel like you could also replace the queryset with `obj.sources.all()` instead of the clunky `__in` query in the `SourceSerializer`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, Nicholas. But won't that create a source field for every Char entry in my JSON, rather than appending a list of sources as a 'reference'?

Comment: okay perhaps I misunderstood what you were trying to achieve. I assumed because you were referencing a `RetrieveModelApiView` and getting the `pk` that you wanted the sources that belong to each individual `Char`. Are you intending on retrieving a list of Chars and returning any Sources that belong in any of them?

Comment: Yes; I need the JSON to include a separate section with all the referenced `Source`s in order to avoid repeating the same information for every `Char` object.

Comment: your desired response is contradictory to what you are trying to achieve. If you visit the url for a specific char id, it will return one char, not an array. In that case, my solution does work. However, if you want to pass more than one char into the the view, you could assign a custom `list_route` and manage either passed in data or query string arguments, create a new serializer that returns a list of chars and a list of sources or you can use a ListApiView and override `def list(request, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: so perhaps clarify what you are trying to achieve and I could provide a new answer

Comment: actually come to think of it in either case... you should be able to override retrieve(request) or list(request) depending on the route and return a custom `rest_framework.response.Response` after calling super. To customize the queryset you can override `get_queryset(request)`, then you can refer to it in the list or retrieve methods as self.get_queryset. This is the preferred way of doing things as it references a cache instance of the queryset instead of creating a new object reference

Comment: In my comment above I actually meant that the `Source` object would be resolved for every member of a `Char`'s locations attribute. Instead of resolving for every member, I want to represent it with an id and include a reference at the end.

Re: your latest comment: that's what I'm struggling with; I don't even know how to pass the `pk` argument as it doesn't seem to be available in my code through the usual `self.kwargs.pop('pk')` method.